# How do I show that in a normed space $| (\|x\|-\|y\|) | \leq \|x-y\|$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, inner-products

How do I show that in a normed space $| (\|x\|-\|y\|) | \leq \|x-y\|$

I need to use normed space axioms but I'm unable to figure it out. I think the scalar axiom and triangle inequality are helpful.

Comment: Observe that $x=(x-y)+y$ and apply the triangle inequality.

Comment: This is  known as the "reverse triangle inequality".

Comment: You can find the proof for absolute value here; [Reverse Triangle Inequality Proof](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127372/reverse-triangle-inequality-proof). Proof for normed spaces is very similar.

Comment: On an unrelated note, this inequality can be used to prove that $f: \mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x)=||x||$ is uniformly continuous which can be used to prove the equivalence of all norms on $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: To complement @user96343's comment I will add links to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/920129/showing-that-a-map-x-to-x-is-continuous) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/569865/in-a-normed-vector-space-v-lvert-rvert-show-that-fv-rightarrow-mathbb).

Answer (score 4):

By triangle inequality:
$$\|x\| = \|x - y + y\| \leq \|x - y\| + \|y\|$$
implies $\|x\| - \|y\| \leq \|x - y\|$. And 
$$\|y\| = \|y - x + x\| \leq \|y - x\| + \|x\|$$
implies $\|y\| - \|x\| \leq \|y - x\| = \|x - y\|$.

Therefore 
$$\left|\|x\| - \|y\|\right| \leq \|x - y\|.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\left \| x \right \|\leq \left \| x-y \right \|+\left \| y \right \|$

$\left \| y \right \|\leq \left \| x-y \right \|+\left \| x \right \|$

so

$\left \| x \right \|-\left \| y \right \|\leq \left \| x-y \right \|$

and

$\left \| y \right \|-\left \| x \right \|\leq \left \| x-y \right \|$

which is what you want.